# Merge two table,same column with empty values

Tags: c#, .net

Two datatables having same columns, unable to merge the table.

[image]

> ```
> Getting error message - 
> **DataExceptionion was caught**
> <target>.EmployeeID and <source>.EmployeeID have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch.
> ```

Code:

```
dttemp = table1.Copy();
dttemp.Merge(table2);
```

How to merge two tables(null values)

Comment: The error message contradicts you assertion. The columns are not the same. To be the same it is not enough to have the same name

Comment: dttemp = table1.Clone(), use clone instead of copy.

Comment: how did you define the table2? table2 should be a clone copy of dttemp or table1.

Comment: Try `dttemp.Merge(table2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);`

Comment: clone() not working gettting an same error.                         dttemp.Merge(table2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore) this works. Thank you all .My question is, Merge will not work if the column has  null values?

Comment: Please provide us full code to represent this error.

Comment: Look at the definition of Merge and its exceptions